# How to make a shine for animation on a sprite

Tags: adobe-illustrator, games, sprite

I am in the process of making a game and would like a sprite to have a shine animation every so often. The attached picture shows the effect I would like to replicate, I have illustrator, with which I am new, and have dug around the menus but cannot replicate the effect.

[image: Shine 1] [image: shine 2]

What tool(s) should I use to achieve this

Comment: Hi Andrew, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a gradient, from white to transparent, make it on its own layer, as a unique object, and then export it as a .png, by itself.

You can do this vertically, or horizontally, then mirror/duplicate whatever you create, and put it on the other side, so you get that fadein/fadeout look.

Make sure you export as a transparent .png, unmatted, so that it's going from white to transparent, without anything else on... i.e. turn all other layers off before exporting.

Then, in whatever rendering/game engine you're using, add this over the top, preferably with an additive blend mode, angle it to your liking, and pass it across (animation) the object you want to have appear as though it's gleaming.

Comment: For best effect, when animating, pass two of these over your object in close succession, the second one faster than the first, and give both a ramped/ease to their animation, slow on, fast out.